# SSL termination when using Zuul or Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Currently our application uses a hardware load balancer for SSL termination. We are beginning to implement a new architecture that breaks the one big application into a set of smaller ones, likely using the Netflix & Spring Cloud tools.

As we look at Zuul one of the questions from the operations team is where are people usually terminating the SSL connections when having lots of connections (and Zuul services)? We did in the load balancer years ago due to the CPU costs of terminating the SSL on the single application server, but if we deploy a set of services on multiple machines does that remove that concern?

So where are people terminating their SSL when using Zuul?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: how have you designed the set-up now ?

Comment: F5 Load balancers with SSL termination.

Answer (score 0):

We have been struggling with this same question.  I hate to put yet another proxy in front of Zuul.  If it really is an edge service and can handle global load balancing and other concerns I would think that Zuul is the likely place to handle SSL.

For now we are going to use an F5 because we have them available.  You could also use a HAProxy software load balancer, NGinX or Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zuul as proxy, what's wrong terminating tls/ssl at zuul? (Assuming all requests goes thru zuul).